# Integração Site - API Instagram - PHP

Tags: php, api, instagram-api

Eu não sei o que aconteceu, mas estava funcionando no meu site a integração do Instagram. Eu fiz uma randomização de fotos. Mas do nada deixou de funcionar, as imagens não aparecem mais.

Pra quem conhece o API Console do Instagram Developers, testei os parâmetros e funcionaram. Alguém sabe se teve alguma modificação na maneira de se autenticar no Instagram... ? Ou se o CURL pode dar problema caso mude a versão do PHP ?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
include_once 'instagram.class.php';
$insta_settings = array(
  'client_id'       => '***********',
  'client_secret'   => '***********',
  'redirect_uri'    => 'http://********.com.br/auth/instagram',
  'scope'           => array('likes')
);

---------------------------------------------------------------

define('INSTAGRAM_ID', '**********');
define('INSTAGRAM_TOKEN', '**********');
$insta_settings['access_token'] = INSTAGRAM_TOKEN;
$instagram  = new Instagram($insta_settings);
$instagram->initRequest('GET');
$instagram->requestUrl('/users/'.INSTAGRAM_ID.'/media/recent');
$images     = $instagram->performRequest();
```

Se eu faço um `print_r($images)` não pega nada.
A classe que estou utilizando é essa:

https://github.com/marlonmarcello/simple-php-instagram-api

Comment: Todos os meus sites q fazia integração com a API do instagram pararam de funcionar. Agora estou usando isso http://instafeedjs.com/

Comment: É mesmo, cara ? Noss.... Vou dar um murro na cara do Instagram.

Comment: @ErlonCharles, por acaso nesse **instafeed.js** tem como fazer a função do **Like** ?

Comment: Dar like em uma imagem? Até agora não vi isso, mas pode estar em implementação

Comment: @ErlonCharles, entendi. E tem como eu colocar uma imagem à minha escolha em uma DIV, por exemplo ? Imagem fixa...

Comment: Tem sim, você pode criar um template para o retorno da(s) imagem(s)

Comment: Entendi. Aprendi bem até essa biblioteca. Não é tão difícil. Obrigado pela indicação. Se quiser coloque como resposta para eu escolher.

Comment: OK vou colocar cmo resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tive um problema parecido com meus sites que utilizavam a api do Intagram, também não sei ao certo o motivo ainda, mas passei a utilizar esta biblioteca para fazer a integração [instafeedjs](http://instafeedjs.com).

### Intalação

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/instafeed.min.js"></script>
```

### Uso básico

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

> obs:
>   Uma forma que eu encontrei de fazer os *likes* nas imagens foi abrir a imagem clicada em um modal assim a pessoa pode dar *like* na imagem direto no instagram

Comment: Valeu, Erlon. Consegui fazer. Ficou mais rápido até do que o outro que estava utlizando. Legal a ideia do Modal. Vou ver se convém aplicar dessa forma. Obrigado.